# Visual Studio 2015 crashes when adding new connection to MySQL

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, mysql-connector

I am having a problem where Visual Studio crashes when I try to create a new connection to MySQL.

Here is my setup:

- Visual Studio 2015
- MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.6
- MySQL Connector/Net 6.9.8
- MySQL Workbench Community 6.3.6

Note that I can connect to MySQL server from Workbench just fine.

Here are the repro steps:

1. Open Visual Studio 2015, do not open any solutions or projects
   (although opening a solution or project makes no difference).
2. In Server Explorer, right-click Data Connections -> Add Connection
3. Choose MySQL Database, with .NET Data Provider for MySQL, -> NEXT
4. Enter server details on the next dialog. TEST the connection -> Shows SUCCESS.
5. Select database -> Shows correct list of databases in dropdown.
6. Click OK.
7. Visual Studio 2015 crashes. I checked the event log, and here is the stack trace:

Application: devenv.exe 
Framework Version: v4.0.30319 
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.

```
Exception Info: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException 
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket() 
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.ReadPacket() 

Exception Info: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException 
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.AuthenticationFailed(System.Exception) 
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.ReadPacket() 
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.Authenticate(Boolean) 
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Authenticate(System.String, Boolean) 
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open() 
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open() 
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder) 
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection() 
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver() 
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection() 
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() 
at MySql.Data.VisualStudio.MySqlConnectionSupport.Open(Boolean) 
at MySql.Data.VisualStudio.MySqlDataConnectionUI.DatabaseExists() 
at MySql.Data.VisualStudio.MySqlDataConnectionUI.okButton_Click(System.Object, System.EventArgs) 
at System.EventHandler.Invoke(System.Object, System.EventArgs) 
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(System.EventArgs) 
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(System.EventArgs) 
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef) 
at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef) 
at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef) 
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
```

Any ideas on what may be causing this? I tried leaving the "Always use this selection" checkbox in the Add New Connection dialog unchecked, as was suggested in a [similar issue with Visual Studio 2013](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?174,630473,630514#msg-630514), but no luck.

I've also tried some of the suggestions from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32037178/cannot-connect-to-mysql-from-visual-studio-2015), but without success.

Comment: In case anyone is still wondering about this crash, it was caused by the max number of connections getting exceeded for MySQL server. Once I removed the limit on number of connections, I was able to add the connection to MySQL just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just converting my comment above to an answer:
The crash was caused by the max number of connections getting exceeded for MySQL server. Once I removed the limit on number of connections in MySQL, I was able to add the connection in Visual Studio just fine.